# call another functions when first function return true, within one onclientclick

Tags: javascript, gridview

I want to call two functions and if the first returns true then continue to the second, and if it returns false then show an error. This would be defined in one onclientclick.

If only one function is to be called after I clicked the button, the function works.

However, if I combine and write it like this:
TestCheckBox() and TestCheckBox2() are same function, I just need it to validate two gridviews

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var TargetBaseControl = null;

window.onload = function () {
    try {
        //get target base control.
        TargetBaseControl =
       document.getElementById('<%= this.GridView1.ClientID %>');
    }
    catch (err) {
        TargetBaseControl = null;
    }
}


function TestCheckBox() {

        if (TargetBaseControl == null) return false;

        //get target child control.
        var TargetChildControl = "chkRow";

        //get all the control of the type INPUT in the base control.
        var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
            if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' &&
        Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0 &&
        Inputs[n].checked)

                return true;


        alert('Select at least one checkbox!');
        return false;

}
</script>
```

The problem is when TestCheckBox() returns true, TestCheckBox2() does not work, in this case it does not validate the checkboxes.

How do I make it work perfectly?

Comment: How are you calling both the functions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:.... OnClientClick = "return (TestCheckBox() && TestCheckBox2());" ...
```

Comment: no, it doesnt work correctly. It doesnt execute TestCheckBox2 when TestCheckBox return true..